# Buying a ferry ticket North Cyprus-Turkey online

Tags: tickets, paperwork, turkey, ferries, northern-cyprus

I'm considering taking the ferry from Girne (North Cyprus) to Tasucu (Turkey) this year, in which case I would probably buy the ticket [online](https://www.akgunlerbilet.com/online_bilet.php)

When buying it, it asks for either a passport number or a Turkish ID card number, as well as the "country".

Does anyone know for sure the following:

1. If using a foreign ID card, should I put the document number in the "passport number" or "Turkish ID card number" field? Or can I use either without issues?
2. In "Country" should I select my cuntry of citizenship or of residence?

Sent an E-mail (in Turkish) to the company, but they haven't replied and it would be very expensive for me to call them (plus I'm too uncomfortable using the language orally).

Comment: NB: on Skype-out, calling Turkish landlines is 2.8p (£0.028) per minute, so it should not be too expensive.

Comment: Seems very clear to me - a foreign ID card is neither a Turkish ID card nor a passport, so you can't use it. If you use a passport, then "country" is the one that issued the passport you're using.

Comment: @ugoren Ferry companies over there will hardly be more restrictive than border authorities

Comment: @Crazydre, If you know that local authorities allow travel with a foreign ID card, I think you should include it (preferably with a link) in the question (and say exactly what kind of ID is it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Managed to reach them on Facebook, and was told to put the ID number in the "passport number" field followed by "kimlik karti" (ID card) in brackets.
2. The Country to be selected is that of which you're a citizen

Answer (score 3):

Where are you from and what is your residence?

If you have a passport, you should use it and put its number into the field "Passport Number". If you don't have a passport but you are allowed to travel around these two countries with an ID card from your country, you can put its number into the same field (if the number will pass the validation).

As a country choose your citizenship country.